# Ошибка Undefined index: state

Tags: php, переменные, логирование

Выдается ошибка в логах сервера
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: state in ..путь к файлу... on line 32

Вот это строка:

```
<div class="<?if($_POST['state']){echo(($_POST['state']) == "true"?"open":"close");}?>" id="basketList">
```

Сделал проверку переменной. Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет проверки на существование переменной:

```
<div class="<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['state']) and $_POST['state']) 
    { 
        echo (($_POST['state']) == "true" ? "open" : "close");
    }
?>" id="basketList">
```

Если в `$_POST['state']` строка "true". Если же булево значение, то кавычки нужно убрать.

Comment: Но вообще подозреваю, что у вас нарушена логика в этом коде. Скорее всего css-класс должен быть либо open, либо close, даже если   $_POST['state'] не определен.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ MAX!. По поводу логики - я пробовал полностью удалять php код в поле класса и жестко прописывать по умолчанию класс close, но тут как раз и ломалась все. А ваш код помог. еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @ВячеславНестеров Если ответ пользователя MAX помог вам, прошу отметить его как Верный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка синтаксиса из-за кавычек, попробуйте строку из примера ниже. Проверять переменную на существование нет нужны, условие уйдет в `else` если значение не соответствует условию либо переменной просто нет.

```html
<div class="<?php echo ($_POST['state'] == 'true') ? 'open' : 'close' ?>" id="basketList">

или

<div class="<?= ($_POST['state'] == 'true') ? 'open' : 'close' ?>" id="basketList">
```

Comment: С кавычками - хорошее замечание - исправил но без проверки все равно выдает ошибку "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: state". Спасибо за ответ!